# What does {id} mean/do in @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm currently in the process of learning Spring and I keep bumping into that in various examples but I haven't found any explanation anywhere

I've also found

```
return "redirect:/delete/{id}"
```

I understand id is a variable, but what does it do. what is the difference between

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete")
```

Taken from this example http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example-mysql/

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")
public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,@PathVariable("id") int id)
{
    employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(id);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employees");
}
```

Model

```
package com.javainterviewpoint;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1280037900360314186L;

private Integer id;
private String name;
private Integer age;
private String dept;
public Employee()
{
    super();
}
public Employee(Integer id, String name, Integer age, String dept)
{
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.dept = dept;
}
public Integer getId()
{
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id)
{
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Have you taken the time to read [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")` mean that you can delete employee with specifc id. The full request can be for example: `http://yourSite.com/delete/42`
Then you can see `@PathVariable("id") int id` - it's mean variable `id` will be contain value from url.
With this aproach you can do something like this:

```
/doSomething/{someUserName}/{someValue}/{someId}
```

and you will have:

```
@PathVariable("someUserName") String someUserName, @PathVariable("someValue") String id, @PathVariable("id") int id
```

Another example:[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

It's a `PathVariable` and you can use it for example when you have users and you to need to edit or delete one user. This will tell to spring method on which user you have clicked.

You can read the section URI Template Pattern of [Spring MVC guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for more clarifications.

With this approach you attach the id of the user to the url you are calling, and Spring will map the id found in url to the variable you define in method `deleteEmployee` (`@PathVariable("id") int id`)

For example you can invoke `deleteEmployee` method with this url:

http://yourUrl/delete/12345

Then `employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(id);` call will be executed with `12345` as id

Comment: Thank you very much. A pity stack only allow me to select one answer.